# PhoneStateListener and TelephonyManager different Asu and dBm values

Tags: android

I need to get some information about the cellular network (GSM or LTE) I'm connected to. One of those information is the signal dBm and ASU level.

I'm using two approaches to get this info. One is setting up a `PhoneStateListener` and the other is trough `TelephonyManager` getting the registered cell info.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
 mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            telephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);

            System.out.println(signalStrength.toString());
            System.out.println("#################");
            CellInfoWcdma registeredCellInfo = (CellInfoWcdma) getRegisteredCellInfo();
            System.out.println(registeredCellInfo.getCellSignalStrength().toString());
            System.out.println(registeredCellInfo.getCellSignalStrength().getDbm());
            System.out.println(registeredCellInfo.getCellSignalStrength().getAsuLevel());
            System.out.println(registeredCellInfo.getCellSignalStrength().getLevel());


        }
    };

    telephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

The output printed in the console is this:

```
I/System.out 
mGsmSignalStrength 20
mGsmBitErrorRate 0
mCdmaDbm -120
mCdmaEcio  -160
mEvdoDbm  -120
mEvdoEcio  -1
mEvdoSnr  -1
mLteSignalStrength  99
mLteRsrp  2147483647
mLteRsrq  2147483647
mLteRssnr  2147483647
mLteCqi  2147483647
gsm|lte
I/System.out: #################
I/System.out: CellSignalStrengthWcdma: ss=6 ber=99
I/System.out: -101
I/System.out: 6
I/System.out: 2
```

When this measure was made, In settings -> about phone -> state -> SIM state, the values shown where **-73 dBm 20 ASU**

I believe that `signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()` gives me the ASU level and from that the dBM are calculated as `-113 + (2 * asu)` So it gives me the `-73 dBm` shown in settings.

Using the `TelephonyManager` i got different values for dBm and ASU.

Shouldn't those be the same?

Comment: One observation that might explain this is -73 - -101 ~= 30, which is the difference between dB's and dBm's.  that leaves only a 3dB difference which at least in fiber optics is "not much" (e.g. "Accuracy is vendor specific but must be better than +/-3 dB" --SFF-8472 spec.)